# Why can't datatables display data in descending order by default?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, datatable

In addition to the normal sorting capability in datatable, I want to display my datatable in descending order (order by id from mysql result) by default. However without any error, it keeps displaying the datatable in ascending order.

Here are what I have done so far:
JS:

```
$('#example').dataTable({
    "aaSorting": [[0, "desc"]]
});
```

and my serverside:
PHP:

```
SELECT s . * , c.name AS cls, sec.name AS sect
                    FROM `student` s
                    INNER JOIN cls c 
                    ON s.cls = c.id
                    INNER JOIN sect sec 
                    ON s.sect = sec.id 
                    ORDER BY s.id DESC
```

HTML:

```
<table class="table table-striped 
 table-bordered bootstrap-datatable datatable" id="example">
//table data here
</table>
```

Any suggestion and help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could it be  that JS is reversing order from SQL?

Comment: Maybe you are ordering twice:
In your SQL: DESC, and then in JS: Again DESC. DESC*DESC=ASC

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the same problem. we can solve it by adding data one by one in data table in descending order. create an empty table by html and

```
var table = $("#example").dataTable();
```

use ajax and get data in descending order in variable.

```
 $.ajax({
          // params
          success(data){
            table.fnClearTable(); // to clear the table
            $.each(data, function(i,item)){
               table.fnAddData([data.item1, data.item2,data.item3,.....]) // adding data
            }
            table.fnDraw(); // re draw the table
      }
    })
```